# LFS:coreutils compile error

Tags: linux, gnu-coreutils, linux-from-scratch

help2man:

> can't get `--help' info from man/cp.td/cp Try`--no-discard-stderr' if
>   option outputs to stderr Makefile:14066: recipe for target 'man/cp.1'
>   failed make[2]: *** [man/cp.1] Error 127 make[2]: Leaving directory
>   '/sources/coreutils-8.23' Makefile:11098: recipe for target
>   'all-recursive' failed make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1 make[1]:
>   Leaving directory '/sources/coreutils-8.23' Makefile:5765: recipe for
>   target 'all' failed make: *** [all] Error 2

Answer (score 0):

There were a few dependency issues fixed in coreutils 8.24
For example see: http://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/commit/?id=v8.23-34-gf51c44b

If you try the make again it might succeed (as cp is now built).

Comment: Thanks,but I can't find configure or Makefile.